# IE7 Set Document Standard Mode

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, internet-explorer-7

I am trying to do some testing on a WinXP machine with IE7 Installed. And noticed The installed Dev Toolbar doesn't give the Document Mode/Browser Mode option the native newer Dev toolbars give on IE.

I have tried few third party options too so set this for my document through the browser but have not been successful.

Any help on **how to force document mode from the browser** on this old machine would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE7 doesn't have the built-in dev toolbar that newer IE versions have; the built-in dev tools was only introduced in IE8. If you have a dev toolbar installed, then it is a plug-in, and not a standard part of the browser.

IE7 also does not have any of the "Compatibility modes" that IE8 and later have. This explains why you can't pick any of them in the dev toolbar; they simply don't exist. It also won't respond to the `X-UA-Compatible` meta tag that you might use in IE8 or later to force it into any particular mode, since it only has one mode that would respond to that tag anyway.

So the only possible modes in IE7 are "Standards mode" and "Quirks mode".

As long as you have a valid doctype, Quirks mode won't come into play, so you're left with just the basic Standards mode. Only one mode available, so therefore no reason for the browser to allow you to change the mode.

If Quirks mode is the issue, you can avoid that by putting a valid doctype at the top of your page, like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
....etc...
```

That's all you can do in IE7 to force the browser mode.